# How to Add multiple nested Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary

```
dicta={'name': 'C','children': {'name': 'testA','children': {'name': 'test_file'}}}
dictb={'name': 'C','children': {'name': 'testA','children': {'name': 'test_fileB','children': {'name': 'test_file'}}}}
dictc={'name': 'C','children':[{"name":"testA","children":[{"name":"test_file"},{'name': 'test_fileB','children': {'name': 'test_file'}}]}]}
```

I want to use `dicta` and `dictb` to get `dictc`；but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function to merge dictionaries and call it recursively:

```py
def merge(dict1, dict2):
  result = {**dict1}

  if 'children' in dict1 and 'children' in dict2:
    if dict1['children']['name'] == dict2['children']['name']:
      result['children'] = [merge(dict1['children'], dict2['children'])]
    else:
      result['children'] = [dict1['children'], dict2['children']]
  elif 'children' in dict1:
    result['children'] = [dict1['children']]
  elif 'children' in dict2:
    result['children'] = [dict2['chidlren']]
  else:
    del result['children']

  return result

dictc = merge(dicta, dictb)
```

You didn't provide many details on how exactly the merge should work, but this example does produce the `dictc` as you want. You may need to tweak something for your needs

Comment: excuse me，now i want to use dictc with dicta  merge,how can i do? like {'name': 'C', 'children': [{'name': 'testA', 'children': [{'name': 'test_file'}, {'name': 'sub_folderX', 'children': {'name': 'file1'}}]}]}     and    {'name': 'H', 'children': {'name': 'testA', 'children': {'name': 'test_file'}}}

Comment: @user12268076 If you have a new question, please write a new question (and please read [how to use the formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). You also need to ensure that you add all of the relevant language tags. More people would have seen this question if you had added the [tag:python] tag

Comment: ok,thanks. this is a new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61908166/how-to-merge-dictionaries?noredirect=1#comment109497562_61908166